# Are all returned values of glGetInternalformat dependant on both the target and format arguments?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

In the [OpenGL 4.6 specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) under section 22.3, a command named **glGetInternalformat** is described which can be used to gather implementation dependent information about  internal formats.

The command have the following signatures listed in the specification:

```
void GetInternalformativ( enum target, enum internalformat, enum pname, sizei count, int *params );
void GetInternalformati64v( enum target, enum internalformat, enum pname, sizei count, int64 *params );
```

The valid values for **pname** according to the specification are:

```
// Supported operations
    
    GL_CLEAR_BUFFER
    GL_CLEAR_TEXTURE
    GL_COMPUTE_TEXTURE
    GL_FILTER
    GL_FRAGMENT_TEXTURE
    GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BLEND
    GL_FRAMEBUFFER_RENDERABLE
    GL_FRAMEBUFFER_RENDERABLE_LAYERED
    GL_GEOMETRY_TEXTURE
    GL_MANUAL_GENERATE_MIPMAP
    GL_READ_PIXELS
    GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ATOMIC
    GL_SHADER_IMAGE_LOAD
    GL_SHADER_IMAGE_STORE
    GL_SIMULTANEOUS_TEXTURE_AND_DEPTH_TEST
    GL_SIMULTANEOUS_TEXTURE_AND_DEPTH_WRITE
    GL_SIMULTANEOUS_TEXTURE_AND_STENCIL_TEST
    GL_SIMULTANEOUS_TEXTURE_AND_STENCIL_WRITE
    GL_SRGB_READ
    GL_SRGB_WRITE
    GL_TESS_CONTROL_TEXTURE
    GL_TESS_EVALUATION_TEXTURE
    GL_TEXTURE_GATHER
    GL_TEXTURE_GATHER_SHADOW
    GL_TEXTURE_SHADOW
    GL_TEXTURE_VIEW
    GL_VERTEX_TEXTURE


// Other
    
    GL_COLOR_COMPONENTS
    GL_COLOR_ENCODING
    GL_COLOR_RENDERABLE
    GL_DEPTH_COMPONENTS
    GL_DEPTH_RENDERABLE
    GL_GET_TEXTURE_IMAGE_FORMAT
    GL_GET_TEXTURE_IMAGE_TYPE
    GL_IMAGE_COMPATIBILITY_CLASS
    GL_IMAGE_FORMAT_COMPATIBILITY_TYPE
    GL_IMAGE_PIXEL_FORMAT
    GL_IMAGE_PIXEL_TYPE
    GL_IMAGE_TEXEL_SIZE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_PREFERRED
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_RED_SIZE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_GREEN_SIZE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_BLUE_SIZE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_ALPHA_SIZE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_DEPTH_SIZE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_STENCIL_SIZE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_SHARED_SIZE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_RED_TYPE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_GREEN_TYPE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_BLUE_TYPE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_ALPHA_TYPE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_DEPTH_TYPE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_STENCIL_TYPE
    GL_INTERNALFORMAT_SUPPORTED
    GL_MAX_COMBINED_DIMENSIONS
    GL_MAX_DEPTH
    GL_MAX_HEIGHT
    GL_MAX_LAYERS
    GL_MAX_WIDTH
    GL_MIPMAP
    GL_NUM_SAMPLE_COUNTS
    GL_READ_PIXELS_FORMAT
    GL_READ_PIXELS_TYPE
    GL_SAMPLES
    GL_STENCIL_COMPONENTS
    GL_STENCIL_RENDERABLE
    GL_TEXTURE_COMPRESSED
    GL_TEXTURE_COMPRESSED_BLOCK_HEIGHT
    GL_TEXTURE_COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE
    GL_TEXTURE_COMPRESSED_BLOCK_WIDTH
    GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_FORMAT
    GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_TYPE
    GL_VIEW_COMPATIBILITY_CLASS
```

My question is if for all those pname values that can be queried, do any of them not require both the target and internalformat parameters? Are there some pnames that will result in the same returned value regardless of which target is used and are there any pnames that return the same value regardless of internalformat? The specification is not clear on this.

The reason I am asking this is because some pnames seems to be information about the internalformat and has nothing to do with the target. I assume that the people behind opengl did not want to create a seperate set of commands for pnames that do not require both target and internalformat and instead used a single set of commands for all cases.

If a list of the pname values for which the target do not matter and a list of pname values for which the internalformat do not matter (if there are any) could be created and these lists are guaranteed to be the same on all platforms, then one could simply wrap the command and hard code a constant value for those arguments and remove the need for those parameters. This would simplify the gathering of information on internalformats and targets (if there are any target specific information).

Comment: "*This would simplify the gathering of information on internalformats and targets*" What exactly are you trying to gather information on that you would need to pull from all of this information? There are a lot of queries, but most of them aren't all that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard makes it pretty clear which things care about the `target` and which do not. It describes how each `pname` query works and it uses specific keywords in those descriptions. Specifically, it says this up-front:

> In the following descriptions, the term *resource* is used to generically refer to an object of the appropriate type that has been created with *internalformat* and *target*.

So, if the description for a query does not use the words "target" or "resource", then it doesn't care about them.